# back button on browser is postback?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, cookies, drop-down-menu, postback

I have a website http://www.dendy.com.au/Page/Home, on the dropdown box there are 2 options, it loads up the session data (newtown) by getting the cinemaid cookie which is fine.  When i change option, it loads the other cinema session data.

The problem is when I load the second session data (Opera Quays) and click on a movie then Press back on the browser (how most people do) its loads the home page again with Newtown data due to the cookie but in the dropbox it still have Qpera Quay selected even though on inspect element Newtown option have the value selected.

I suspect this is due to cache of the page. So it will select the dropdown option that i selected previously but load the sessions data of newtown from the cookie.

If there a way to fix it?
Here is my code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get cinemaid  from  cookie in the usercontrol base class 
    IList<ORM.Cinema> cinemaList = DAL.DataClasses.CinemaGroup.GetCinemasInGroupByCinemaId(cinemaId);
    //if there's only 1 cinema, hide the cinema selection area
    if (cinemaList.Count() == 1)
    {
        SelectCinemaDiv.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        //set the default cinema dropdownlist selection
        CinemaDropDownList.DataSource = cinemaList;
        CinemaDropDownList.DataBind();
        CinemaDropDownList.SelectedValue = cinemaId.ToString();
        cinemaId = new Guid(CinemaDropDownList.SelectedValue);
    }

        //loads sessions data
    SessionTimeLiteral.Text = LoadCinemaSessionsDirect.LoadCinemaSessionsForOneCinema(cinemaId.ToString(), thisInstance.IncludeElementInstanceId.ToString());
```

I tried to use !Postback but no luck

```
//if there's only 1 cinema, hide the cinema selection area
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (cinemaList.Count() == 1)
        {
            SelectCinemaDiv.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {


            //set the default cinema dropdownlist selection
            CinemaDropDownList.DataSource = cinemaList;
            CinemaDropDownList.DataBind();
            CinemaDropDownList.SelectedValue = cinemaId.ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cinemaId = new Guid(CinemaDropDownList.SelectedValue);
    }
```

Comment: It's not really the cache but the View State. Try disabling the View State on the control in question: `<asp:DropDownList ID="CinemaDropDownList" runat="server" EnabledViewState="false" />`. If that works, good. If not, well, it was worth a shot. :)

Comment: Thanks, this didnt work unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a Session variable to store what the user selected? Then on all of your pages in the page load you can swap it by checking the session data?

```
Session["UserSelection"] = CinemaDropDownList.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: I tried usisng sessions but no luck.. When the user presses back on browser. it loads the cache of the previous page and never hits back the server (doesn't hit page load method)

Comment: @user3060334 is this more of a bug or is the flow of your application depending on the user using the back button? There are some javascript tricks you can use to try and stifle the back button

Comment: I thought about force refreshing the page when there is a value for windows.history.forward() but you cant check if there is a value for it
any other js suggestions?